# std::move between unique_ptr and another that it owns

Tags: c++, tree, nested, move, unique-ptr

Consider some class/struct

```
struct Foo{
    int val = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> child_a = NULL;
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> child_b = NULL;
    Foo(int val_):val(val_){}
    ~Foo(){std::cout<<"Deleting foo "<<val<<std::endl;}
};
```

as you might construct in a doubly linked list/binary tree or similar.

Now,  consider that in such a list we have several such `Foo`s which point to each other in a tree like fashion e.g. through

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> root = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(0));
root->child_a = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(1));
root->child_b = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(2));
root->child_a->child_a = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(3));
root->child_a->child_b = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(4));
root->child_b->child_a = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(5));
root->child_b->child_b = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo(6));
```

In this context, if I write

```
root = NULL
```

then all the linked children get deleted and I get output that looks something like

```
Deleting foo 0
Deleting foo 1
Deleting foo 3
Deleting foo 4
Deleting foo 2
Deleting foo 5
Deleting foo 6
```

My question then, is what *exactly* is happening when I do something like this

```
root = std::move(root->child_a);
```

The output in such a situation looks like

```
Deleting foo 0
Deleting foo 2
Deleting foo 5
Deleting foo 6
```

leaving only the `child_a` branch in place of the original `root` as one might hope.

But looking at this I realise I'm not completely sure how the `std::move` works under the hood here, and the "expected behavior" really seems to be taking the self-referential move for granted. I had always broadly thought that a move like this

```
a=std::move(b);
```

functioned very roughly as

```
a = NULL;
b.release();
a.get() = b.get();
```

but of course this can't be right here, because the first `NULL` would destruct `b` before it could replace the `a` which has just been removed.

Instead I imagine something like this is happening

```
b.release();
c = b.get();
a = NULL;
a.get() = c;
```

such that `b` is moved into some new raw pointer `c` so that `a` can be deleted without interfering with the original `b`.

But it took a bit of thought an experimentation to try to figure out what is going on here, and I'm still not sure, which is a bit unnerving when a) reading code with such uses whilst b) the vast majority of tutorials I can find on unique_ptrs just don't mention what to expect when moving nested pointers to each other.

Can anyone elaborate what is actually happening here and perhaps point me to a good resource?

Comment: `b.get()` after `b.release()` is nonsense. `std::move` does not perform any of those sections, they are performed by the move constructor.

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) has all the nitty gritty details you would ever need to solve your problem.

Comment: Do it yourself. You can look at the move assignment implementation. It's available in <memory>. You seem to expect SO community to do it for you.

Comment: You don't need to know about `r.get_deleter`. All what you need is contained in `reset(r.release())`. I also can say the same thing about you, who did not attempt to research the problem but chose an easy way of delegating it to other people.

Comment: @273K I *did* try to research the problem based on using the usual resources I know. I'm not well versed in how to read the contents of <memory> or where to look etc. This site is full of questions about simple things - those people are not being obnoxious. They are learning and asking questions. Responding "do it yourself" to someone who *is admitting* they don't even know what the "it" they are supposed to do is, is just being horrible. I'm not "delegating" anything, I'm asking  - *the point of the site*. Straight up being rude is not analogous to asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

> [std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset)
>
> **void reset( pointer ptr = pointer() ) noexcept;**
>
> Given current_ptr, the pointer that was managed by *this, performs
> the following actions, in this order:
>
> 1. Saves a copy of the current pointer old_ptr = current_ptr
> 2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument current_ptr = ptr
> 3. If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object if(old_ptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr).

> [std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D)
>
> **unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) noexcept;**
>
> Move assignment operator. Transfers ownership from r to *this as if
> by calling **reset(r.release())** followed by an assignment of
> get_deleter() from std::forward<Deleter>(r.get_deleter())